# Why isn't this regex working in javascript (works in perl)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match the following string,

`Apache/2.2.6 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.6 OpenSSL/0.9.7a DAV/2 PHP/5.2.13`

with the following regex,

`(?:Apache.(\w+))?.*(?:OpenSSL.([\w.]+))?.*(?:PHP.([\w.]+))?`

Since the `XXX/version` pairs may not exist, so I added a `?` after each non-capture matching groups

But only the first version string is matched,

```
var re = /(?:Apache.([\w.]+))?.*(?:OpenSSL.([\w.]+))?.*(?:PHP.([\w.]+))?/;
var captures = re.exec('Apache/2.2.6 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.6 OpenSSL/0.9.7a DAV/2 PHP/5.2.13');
console.log (captures);

// captures[1] = '2.2.6'
// captures[2] = undefined
// captures[3] = undefined
```

Any ideas? Removing the '?' works and I don't know why (works with perl)

**EDIT**

A valid regex that "works" could be (without the '?'),

`(?:Apache.(\w+)).*(?:OpenSSL.([\w.]+)).*(?:PHP.([\w.]+))`

Comment: @anubhava you mean the valid regex?

Comment: I meant few more samples of input data like `Apache/2.2.6 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.6 OpenSSL/0.9.7a DAV/2 PHP/5.2.13`

Answer (score 2):

.* is greedy so I'm not surprised it's not capturing beyond the first group.  What surprises me is that it worked at all anywhere.  Make those catch-alls lazy and un-group the non-capturing and capturing groups and it seems to work:

```
(?:Apache.)(\w+)?.*?(?:OpenSSL.)([\w.]+)?.*?(?:PHP.)([\w.]+)?
```